# multiprocessing don't start

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i just started learning about multiprocessing module today and i was trying this code but it didn't work and i don't know why  it doesn't give me any error or any thing it just end the program normally with out printing any thing here is my simple code :

```
import multiprocessing
def x ():
    print ("hi")
example=multiprocessing.Process(target=x)
example.start()
```

it works when i do this :

```
import multiprocessing
def x ():
    print ("hi")
example=multiprocessing.Process(target=x())
```

but it will not be useful to me like that because i need to use the `join()` and the `start()`

and i am using python 3.5.2

Comment: Does it work if you add `example.join()`?

Comment: I don't see why the first example wouldn't work, what error do you get?

Comment: no  it  just do the same thing even if i add example.join() it just end the program normally with out any printing

Comment: i don't get any error it just end the program with out any error or any printing

Comment: You didn't `join` your process.

Comment: What OS are you on? There's no `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard here.

Comment: i don't think i need the if __name__ == '__main__'

Answer (score 0):

Umm, you can still use `start` and `join`

```
import multiprocessing
def x ():
    print ("hi")
example=multiprocessing.Process(target=x)
example.start() # START
example.join() # JOIN
```

Running in the python repl, I get,

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> def x ():
...     print ("hi")
... 
>>> example=multiprocessing.Process(target=x)
>>> example.start(); example.join()
hi
>>>
```

The only reason the second example seems to work is because you are calling `x` (notice `target=x()` vs `target=x`).

Your first example works but without `join`, the program is terminated after main is finished (but before the child process is finished). This creates a zombie process and possibly prevents it from doing more work, like printing `hi` to standard output

Comment: That's running `x` in the main process, not the new one you create.

Comment: as long as that cod is working for you then i guess i am having problem with my computer thanks 
i am going to look for more answers until tomorrow and if nothing worked for me then its defiantly a problem with my computer