# multiprocessing not working (oserror:[Errno 22] Invalid argument )

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i am using python3.5.2 and i am trying to learn about multiprocessing but it doesn't work for me it doesn't show me any error or any thing it just finish the program normally with out doing anything i already asked about this if you want to see my question for more details

[multiprocessing don't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459184/multiprocessing-dont-start)

i tried everything and all the time is the same problem when i searched i found lot of people having the same problem every one was telling them that its the IDLE problem so i tried and i opened the python file with out the IDLE and now thankfully i had error message but i am beginner so i couldn't understand what is the problem , here is the problem :

[image: and thanks for your help]

Comment: Did you place any of your files in a folder with a unicode name? Or do you access such a file?

Comment: @KlausD. i am beginner on programming and computers and i am learning from internet there for i have no idea what is unicode name but i am going to search about it now

Comment: Basically it is any name which has other characters than a-z and 0-9. Your name on SO would be a good example.

Comment: @KlausD. thank you so much yes the problem was the file name in arabic but now i made it in english and its working :)

Answer (score 3):

For an explanation of why the `if __name__ == '__main__':` part is necessary, see Programming guidelines.

> **Python » Documentation** [Safe importing of main module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods)