# imshow() returns invalid dimensions for 2D array when using multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, multiprocessing, imshow

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing module to create figures from 2D arrays faster. In the code below I create a 2D array from a hdf5 data file (please message me if you would like a sample file to test on). Using `multiprocessing.Pool`, I try to pass this array to the `map` function but it raises `TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data`. I've checked to make sure my array is 2 dimensions using `da.shape`, so I'm not sure why it isn't working for me. Any help is much appreciated!

To `import yt`, see [yt-project.org/#getyt](http://yt-project.org#getyt).

P.S. This is my first question on Stack Overflow so please let me know if/how I can improve.

```
import yt
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Array

fl_nm = raw_input("enter filename: ").strip()
level = int(raw_input("resolution level: ").strip())

ds = yt.load(fl_nm)
all_data_level_x = ds.covering_grid(level=level,left_edge=[-3.70281620e+21,0.00000000e+00,-3.70281620e+21],dims=ds.domain_dimensions*2**level)
disp_array = []
for x in xrange(0,16*2**level):
    vbin = []
    for z in xrange(0,80*2**level):
        v = []
        for y in xrange(0,8*2**level):
            vel = all_data_level_x["velocity_magnitude"][x,y,z].in_units("km/s")
            v.append(vel)
            sigma = np.sqrt(np.sum((v - np.mean(v))**2) / np.size(v))
            vbin.append(sigma)
        disp_array.append(vbin)
    print "{0:.1f} %".format((x+1)*100/float(16*2**level))

da = np.array(disp_array)
print "fixed resolution array created"

def __main__(data_array):
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    plt.imshow(data_array, origin = "lower", aspect = "equal",  extent=[-1.2,10.8,-1.2,1.2])
    plt.colorbar(fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
    print "plot created. Saving figure..."
    fig_nm = 'velocity_disp_{0}_lvl_{1}.png'.format(fl_nm[-4:],level)
    plt.savefig(fig_nm)
    plt.close()
    print "File saved as: " + fig_nm
    return

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.map(__main__,da)
```

Comment: Read this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644232/multiprocessing-not-working-oserrorerrno-22-invalid-argument/43658257#43658257

Answer (score 0):

`pool.map(func, iterable[, chunksize])` iterates the `da`. So if `da` is a 2-D array like `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. The input of your `__main__` function will be `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` for every process.

I'm not sure what you want to do, so if you really want to get a full help, you can upload your executable project(to github or something else, whatever) and I will check.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fe_1dMIH_pc3FHWXMwcUxoanc/view?usp=sharing Here is the hdf5 file.

Comment: @ElliottWilliams I have run your script with only changing it to python3(btw, python2 is dying, do not use python2 anymore.). And I check the shape of `da` with `dual_8r_hdf5_plt_cnt_0063` as `fl_nm` and `2` as `level`. In this case, `da`'s shape is `(20480, 10240)`. And then function `map` iterate this array, so `data_array`'s shape in every process is `(10240,)`. Do you think this is a valid shape for a image?

Comment: I was thinking I could use multiple processes working together to generate a single image. As you may have realized in running my script, the time it takes to generate the png grows very fast as you increase the resolution level.

Comment: @ElliottWilliams Surely you can, but it doesn't mean you can simply pass the image to a multiprocess-based function. Computer is stupid, you need to specify what it should do. You critical problem is how to generate plot using multi cpus in python.

Comment: Ok, glad the plausibility is there. Do you have any suggestions on doing that?