# PyCharm multiprocessing errors: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument, PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, multiprocessing

I'm executing these 2 lines in PyCharm 2020.2.3 console:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.Pool()
```

And getting these 2 errors:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.Pool()
<multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x0529AA90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path

  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 231, in _get_code_from_file
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\1\\PycharmProjects\\untitled2\\<input>'
```

...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644232/multiprocessing-not-working-oserrorerrno-22-invalid-argument

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 thx for the link, but there is no answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this issue is known by PyCharm devs and is waiting for the fix:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36151?_ga=2.215165010.494317185.1602845769-2057238290.1555425748